# add dom before current dom, and keep current dom stay in the viewport

Tags: javascript, css, dom

Assume there is a scroll list, when I insert some new DOM append to the current dom, it works fine.
pullup

[image]

But if I insert some new DOM before, the new DOM will be in the viewport, and the old DOM will be push down.
pulldown

[image]

Is there a way that I can make pulldown behave like pullup? Without manually set scrollTop after?

Comment: Can you show some representative code ("*[mcve]*")? If the 'old DOM' has an `id` you could easily enough prepend the 'new DOM' contents, and then update the hash of the current page to `#oldDOMId`. Though there would be some visible movement.

Answer (score 0):

In Google Chrome, I cannot reproduce the behavior you describe. Could there be a difference in how browsers manage maintaining scroll positions upon DOM edits?

In Safari, I do see the behavior you describe. I'm not aware of any different injection methods to bypass the issue, and I don't think css-like tricks such as `translateY` or `position: absolute` are the way to go...

So, that brings us to the one option you said you didn't want to use... Modifying `scrollTop`. I don't see many problems with an approach like this though...

```
function scrollSafeInsertBefore(fragment, el, scrollContainer) {
  var scroller = scrollContainer || document.body;
  var parent = el.parentElement;
  var aboveScroll = el.getBoundingClientRect().top < 0;

  if (aboveScroll) {
    var st = parent.scrollHeight;
    parent.insertBefore(fragment, el);

    var dy = parent.scrollHeight - st;
    scroller.scrollTop += dy;   // Move back the height change
  } else {
    parent.insertBefore(fragment, el); // Normal injection
  }
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pq4t2zbn/ (press the *insert* button)